# How can I transform the following script into a function for a package?

Tags: r, function

I have the following data as an example:

```
IID<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
KB<-c(345,1234,2000,1567,
      376,1657,9656,234,
      1865,1565,123,111,
      1999,2032,1565,234)
data<-cbind(IID,KB)
```

I wrote a script to process it and give me some outcomes:

```
results_kb <- function(class)  {
  this_iids_roh <- dat[class,]
  my_list<-c("Sum_long"=sum(this_iids_roh$KB[this_iids_roh$KB>=1500]),
             "N_long"=length(this_iids_roh$KB[this_iids_roh$KB>=1500]),
             "Sum_short"=sum(this_iids_roh$KB[this_iids_roh$KB<1500]),
             "N_short"=length(this_iids_roh$KB[this_iids_roh$KB<1500]))
  return(my_list)
}

dat <- data.table::as.data.table(data)
dat$IID<-as.factor(dat$IID)
data.table::setkey(dat,"IID")
results <- c()
nLevels <- length(levels(dat$IID))
start <- proc.time()
pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = nLevels, style = 3)
for (i in 1:nLevels){
  this_iid <- levels(dat$IID)[i]
  results <- rbind(results,results_kb(this_iid))
  setTxtProgressBar(pb,i)
}
close(pb)
proc.time()-start
results<-data.frame(levels(dat$IID),results)
results$IID<-results$levels.dat.IID.
results[results==0] <- NA
```

I created first a function that gives me the outcome table and then I processed the dataset I want to analyze. I added a time indicator because this script is to process very large samples. As you can test it works perfectly.

Now I want to write my own package, so I have to reduce all this into functions. The first part of the script is already in a function. For the second part I have tried the following:

```
rohsum<-function(data){
  dat <- data.table::as.data.table(data)
  dat$IID<-as.factor(dat$IID)
  data.table::setkey(dat,"IID")
  results <- c()
  nLevels <- length(levels(dat$IID))
  start <- proc.time()
  pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = nLevels, style = 3)
  for (i in 1:nLevels){
    this_iid <- levels(dat$IID)[i]
    results <- rbind(results,results_kb(this_iid))
    setTxtProgressBar(pb,i)
  }
  close(pb)
  proc.time()-start
  results<-data.frame(levels(dat$IID),results)
  results$IID<-results$levels.dat.IID.
  results[results==0] <- NA
  return(results)
}
```

However this seems not to work, since when I tried to run `rohsum(data)` I get the following error message:
`Error in results_kb(this_iid) : object 'dat' not found`

Even more, If I tried to run several times I get the following:

[image]

How can I solve this issue to be able to build my own package?

Comment: THANKS phiver1. results_kb is the function I defined before and I already loaded in R. Why is not working? Should I include this function (results_kb) in that second function (rohsum).

Comment: Thank you very much! And why is that if I dont include the second part in a function it works perfectly, but when I create a function stops working. I mean, dat[class,] is being found when I run the first example of the code (whithout the function in the second part of the script).

Comment: By the way, solved the dat not found by adding: ```data<-as.data.frame(cbind(IID,KB))``` But I still get NA in everyrow... Dont know why.

Comment: R packages can have scripts.  If you put myscript.R in the demo directory then it can be run using `demo("myscript")`  .  You can optinally add a `00Index` file to the demo directory which has one line per script with the name of the script without the extension followed by space and the description on the same line.